# Why doesn't this return me both speeds and instead it keeps giving this error? Using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the result from the speedtest but i can't seem to get a grasp of them, it also keeps giving me this kind of error:
c:\Users\39334\Desktop\VSC\Section 51\main.py:15: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROME_PATH)

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60701/devtools/browser/4e955ab0-35c8-4c75-9ed8-ee96d8acb5cb
[28336:3084:0410/195900.885:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(34)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate

[28336:27124:0410/195900.885:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(34)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate

[28336:24676:0410/195900.885:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(34)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate

[28336:17748:0410/195900.885:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(34)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate

[28336:26724:0410/195900.885:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(34)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate

[28336:23952:0410/195900.885:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(34)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate

[28336:3084:0410/195900.901:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(34)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate

[28336:24356:0410/195903.058:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(222)] [19:59:03.059] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Un dispositivo
collegato al sistema non Þ in funzione. (0x1F)
[28336:3084:0410/195904.608:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(34)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate

[28336:3084:0410/195904.795:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(34)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate

[28336:3084:0410/195906.748:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(34)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate

[28336:24676:0410/195906.861:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(34)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate

[28336:3084:0410/195952.093:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(34)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate

PS C:\Users\39334\Desktop\VSC\Section 51>

I created this class :

from selenium import webdriver
import time

class TwitterBot:

```
def __init__(self, driver) :
    self.driver = driver
    self.up = 0
    self.down = 0

def get_internet_speed(self):
    self.driver.get("https://www.speedtest.net/it")
    time.sleep(6)

    accetta = self.driver.find_element(by="id", value = "onetrust-accept-btn-handler")
    accetta.click()

    time.sleep(5)

    vai = self.driver.find_element(by="class name", value = 'start-text')
    vai.click()

    time.sleep(50)

    up_speed = self.driver.find_element(by="class name", value = 'download-speed').text
    down_speed = self.driver.find_element(by="class name", value = 'upload-speed').text

    time.sleep(5)

    return up_speed, down_speed
```

My goal is to get the upload and download speed so that if they are down a certain threshold, a bot will tweet at the internet provider. The problem is that i can't get the script to return those value to the console while testing.
I tried using also the xpath method but it keeps giving the same error and it says it can't find what i am looking for.
What am i missing? thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of detail here, but this is NOT the right way to solve this problem.  There is an existing Python module that runs speedtest from a command-line interface.  That's the right place to start.

https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. The only problem is that I am currently following an online course and the topic now is selenium webdriver, so I should try solving it using that.